# implementing xcache to speed up magento

Tags: magento-1.7, cache

I'm using Magento ver. 1.7.0.2 on a 64-bit Centos box with litespeed web server. Recently I re-compiled easyapache to include xcache for the purpose of increasing site speed. However now I'm not sure if there's something "additional" I need to do within magento config file (local.xml) as googling for answers is some what unclear. Many users report "add memcache" while some say "add memcache or APC" and then provide config local.xml config settings for APC. So, I'd like to know if enabiling xcache via easyapache is all that is needed to benefit magento's speed, or if I need to also edit the config file?

For example, do I add something like the following?

```
<cache>
    <backend>xcache</backend>
    <prefix>MAGE_</prefix>
</cache>
```

***Edit: adding my COMPLETE local.xml file below ... please let me know what to edit exactly. The "X's" represent sensitive data that I have commented out.

```
<config>
  <global>
    <install>
      <date><![CDATA[XXX, XX XXX XXXX XX:XX:XX +0000]]></date>
    </install>
    <crypt>
      <key><![CDATA[XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX]]></key>
    </crypt>
    <disable_local_modules>false</disable_local_modules>
    <resources>
      <db>
        <table_prefix><![CDATA[]]></table_prefix>
      </db>
      <default_setup>
        <connection>
          <host><![CDATA[localhost]]></host>
          <username><![CDATA[XXX_XXX]]></username>
          <password><![CDATA[XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX]]></password>
          <dbname><![CDATA[XXX_XXX]]></dbname>
          <initStatements><![CDATA[SET NAMES utf8]]></initStatements>
          <model><![CDATA[mysql4]]></model>
          <type><![CDATA[pdo_mysql]]></type>
          <pdoType><![CDATA[]]></pdoType>
          <active>1</active>
        </connection>
      </default_setup>
    </resources>
    <session_save><![CDATA[files]]></session_save>      
  </global>
  <admin>
    <routers>
      <adminhtml>
        <args>
          <frontName><![CDATA[XXXXXXXXXXXX]]></frontName>
        </args>
      </adminhtml>
    </routers>
  </admin>
</config>
```

Comment: Would be great if you can add the final solution if you had any.

Comment: OPT cache will help better than varnish cache.

Answer (score 1):

The best thing to do is look at the ***[app/etc/local.xml.additional](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/etc/local.xml.additional#L38)*** file which is a reference file that ships with the codebase. Of particular interest in your case:

```
<global>
    <!-- ... -->
    <cache>
        <backend></backend><!-- apc / memcached / xcache / empty=file -->
        <!-- ... -->
    </cache>
    <!-- ... -->
</global>
```

Which lets you know that [there is an `xcache` cache backend available](https://github.com/benmarks/magento-mirror/blob/1.7.0.2/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Cache.php#L179).

Comment: If possible please expand your answer because simply putting "xcache" between <backend></backend> will break the site. Also, your answer is a simple copy/paste from google which i've seen several times ... doesn't explain how to truly implement xcache.

Comment: 1) I didn't use Google. I read the code. Additionally, I linked you to hosted source and pointed out the mapping of config to cache model backend so that you can help yourself. 2) I answered the question you asked: *"...or if I need to also edit the config file?"* Want a more specific answer, ask a more specific question.

Comment: How would my local.xml be edited because implementing the above referenced code will cause the site to throw all types of errors.

Comment: See https://www.properhost.com/support/kb/31/How-to-enable-XCache-in-Magento with some more details, also on errors encountered. But even with that implementation I still had errors like `fast_backend must implement the Zend_Cache_Backend_ExtendedInterface interface`

Comment: Also found Zend issue on this opened here http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-9150 : `Xcache can't be used as fast cache backend with Zend_Cache_Backend_TwoLevels
Fast_backend must implement the Zend_Cache_Backend_ExtendedInterface interface error appears.
Need implement Zend_Cache_Backend_ExtendedInterface`

Comment: Should be something like this: `<cache>
<backend>xcache</backend><!-- apc / memcached / xcache / empty=file --><backend_options><connection></connection> <enable_two_levels>true</enable_two_levels> </backend_options><slow_backend>database</slow_backend><slow_backend_store_data></slow_backend_store_data> <auto_refresh_fast_cache></auto_refresh_fast_cache> </cache>` but still getting errors.